# Objects Rendering Upside-down

Tags: modeling, rendering

So I am very new to blender and am currently following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg3tNXRgUDs for building little whipped cakes. My project looks fine before rendering and even looks the same in cycles. However, when I finally render the image, the whipped cream on top is upside down. I have no clue what I have done wrong. How can I fix this? How can I avoid this in the future?
[image: Here is what my cakes look like.]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link and paste it into your question. We'll then be able to see what's going on and advise.

Comment: I just shared, however, now the file is showing it upside down as well, which it hadn't been previously.

Comment: My guess is, you rotated your view in such a way that you were looking at your object from the bottom and you designed it like so. After reopening it, the view did reset to normal.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you've accidentally inserted a keyframe in the 'Mode' of your first *Simple Deform* modifier, setting it to 'Twist'?  :

[image]

Can't be sure, but if you right-click > Delete Key Frame on that bar, and set the Mode to 'Taper' instead.. your cream is nicely piped.

You can do them all at once (if they're all selected), by taking those actions on the active object with <kbd>Alt</kbd> held down.

Comment: In addition to the the other comment and answer, you seem to have managed to create several duplicate windows. To be honest I'd start again from scratch with a new file and be very careful to follow the tutorial exactly. In fact I'd look for complete beginners tutorials with spoken commentary first rather than having to follow subtitles.